# Flutter Float and Fade In Animation for Widgets in Column with Loading for the First Time

Tags: flutter, animation, widget

I am trying to create animated screens in which for example, when the screen is loaded, each one would contain a column with widgets. What I would like to do is, when the screen is loaded, have each widget in the column float in from off screen (from bottom) in the order in which they appear.

I have been searching but cannot seem to find a solution. How may I achieve this?

Comment: Add your code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done something that might be what you want. However, to make it so each element animates after the last one for itself and not all together I had to use the `ListView.builder` to get the `index`. You can use the `Column` widget if you can find out the `index` of the element.

Here is the code:

The home screen:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:testing/fade_in_from_bottom.dart';

void main() => runApp(App());

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Widget> children = <Widget>[
    Container(
      height: 32.0,
      color: Colors.amber,
    ),
    Container(
      height: 32.0,
      color: Colors.black,
    ),
    Container(
      height: 32.0,
      color: Colors.purple,
    ),
    Container(
      height: 32.0,
      color: Colors.green,
    ),
    Container(
      height: 32.0,
      color: Colors.indigo,
    ),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: children.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return FadeInFromBottom(
                  key: UniqueKey(), // this is very important
                  index: index,
                  child: children[index],
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the `FadeInFromBottom` widget I made:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FadeInFromBottom extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FadeInFromBottomState createState() => _FadeInFromBottomState();
  final Key key;
  final Duration animationDuration;
  final Duration offsetDuration;
  final Widget child;
  final int index;
  FadeInFromBottom({
    @required this.key,
    @required this.child,
    @required this.index,
    this.animationDuration = const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
    this.offsetDuration = const Duration(milliseconds: 800),
  }) : super(key: key); // this line is important
}

// How to add AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin? Follow steps 1, 2 and 3:

// 1. add AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin to FadeInFromBottom widget State
class _FadeInFromBottomState extends State<FadeInFromBottom>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin, AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true; // 2. add this line
  double progress = 0.0;

  Animation<double> animation;
  AnimationController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    final Duration offsetDuration =
        widget.offsetDuration == null ? 0.0 : widget.offsetDuration;
    final int index = widget.index == null ? 0 : widget.index;
    
    // we await the future to create the animation delay
    Future.delayed(offsetDuration * index).then(
      (_) {
        controller = AnimationController(
            duration: widget.animationDuration, vsync: this);
        animation = Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(
          CurvedAnimation(
            parent: controller,
            curve: Curves.linear,
          ),
        )..addListener(() {
            setState(() => progress = animation.value);
          });

        controller.forward();
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context); // 3. add this line
    return Opacity(
      opacity: progress,
      child: Transform.translate(
        offset: Offset(
          0.0,
          (1.0 - progress) * 999.0,
        ),
        child: widget.child,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Don't forget to add the `key: UniqueKey()` property, without it the animations will be messed up.

Comment: Thanks. This works great. The only thing is it replays the animation when I changes to the UI. Like switching between page views (it is in one of the pages).

Comment: I'm glad it works for you. To stop it from animating every time you switch from one page to another you can add the `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` to the `FadeInFromBottom` widget. I added 3 lines of code to the `FadeInFromBottom` widget's state. The first is where the declaration for the class for the state of the `FadeInFromBottom`. The second one is inside the class (adding the getter `wantKeepAlive`) and the third is in the `build` method (calling `super.build(context)`). Please check it out and let me know if it works for you.